# Matlab: How to save num2str(i).mat in matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, mat-file

Suppose I have a for loop and want to save a mat file at each iteration with the name of the iteration. I made it as below but it does not work.

```
clc;
clear;
for i=1:3
    filename=num2str(i);
    save(filename,'.mat')
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first input to `save` needs to be a string, you're passing *two* inputs to `save` (`filename` and `'.mat'`). `save` has no way of automatically combining your filename with the `.mat` extension you've provided and instead ends up looking for a variable named `'.mat'` which is obviously going to result in errors.

You want to concatenate these two strings into *one* string (using `[]` or `strcat`) and pass this as the first input to `save`.

```
save([filename, '.mat'])
```

Alternately, you *could* just provide `filename` because the `.mat` extension will automatically be appended assuming that `filename` doesn't already have an extension. Personally, I don't particularly like this method as I use `.` in my filenames, but if you don't this would likely work.

```
save(filename)
```